# Adjusting booktitle in inproceedings in a makebst-file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, custom-bib

I have used `makebst` to create my Harvard-bibliography.

> Jiang, W., Koguchi, K. and Schulzrinne, H. (2003), ‘QoS evaluation of VoIP end- points’, ‘IEEE International Conference on Communications, 2003. ICC’03.’, pp. 1917–1921.

The entry in the bib-file:

```
@inproceedings{jiang2003qosevaluation,
title = {{QoS} evaluation of {VoIP} end-points},
booktitle = {{IEEE} International Conference on Communications, 2003. {ICC'03.}},
author = {Jiang, W. and Koguchi, K. and Schulzrinne, H.},
month = may,
year = {2003},
pages = {1917--1921}}
```

I want to remove the quotes around the booktitle ‘IEEE International Conference on Communications, 2003. ICC’03.’ and make it italic, for all *inproceedings* and probably for other entries too.

Which alternative in which question in the .btj-file should I choose to make it like mentioned above?

I'm using Lyx, so if it's possible I could add a TeX command to adjust.

Comment: Should that read .dbj-file instead of .btj-file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the makebst-session:

> COLLECTION/PROCEEDINGS TITLES (if quoted title)
>
> (*) Quote collection and proceedings titles too
>
> (x) Collection and proceedings titles not in quotes

Choose x.

It's unnecessary to redo the whole session (like I did four times), just open up the dbj-file and comment out the wrong answers, and remove the comment-sign (%) at the correct answers. Just remove one comment-sign at the relevant answer, sometimes there's a purpose to have a second comment-sign at some answers.

Then open up your terminal and call on the edited dbj-file that generates the bst-file.

```
latex foo.dbj
```

Where foo is the name you choose in the beginning of the session.